# What Python regular expression will capture overlapping two-word sequences (including contractions) in texts?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

What tweaking of the pattern is required to achieve the desired output?

```
from re import findall

s= '''one can't two won't three'''

pat = r'(?=(\b\w+[\w\'\-’]*\b \b\w+[\w\'\-’]*\b))'

s2 = findall(pat, s)
print(s2)

# actual output
# ["one can't", "can't two", 't two', "two won't", "won't three", 't three']

# desired output
# ["one can't", "can't two", "two won't", "won't three"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem is that the word boundaries `\b` match after an apostrophe, the simple fix is to use a lookbehind to assert that the match isn't preceded by an apostrophe.

The lookbehind:

```
(?<!\')
```

The complete regex:

```
(?<!\')(?=(\b\w+[\w\'\-’]*\b \b\w+[\w\'\-’]*\b))
```

See it in action at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/prRSuk/1).

Comment: That works. Also I think one can remove all the word boundary markers except the initial one:

**pat = r'(?<!\')(?=(\b\w+[\w\'\-’]* \w+[\w\'\-’]*))'**

Comment: @NicholasNickleby You may want to keep the one at the end, but yes, the two in the middle can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
(?:^|\s+)(?=(\S+\s+\S+))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/12)